# How to assign unique id to swt widget and get it in swtbot?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I want to assign a unique id to swt widget, and than get back the widget in SWTBot test with this unique id.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this.

---

I think your best option is to use the method [`Widget#setData(Object)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#setData%28java.lang.Object%29) to set the id.

You can generate a (pseudo) random id using:

```
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
widget.setData(id);
```

(or use any id generation method you want).

To find your widget, you would have to search through the children of the `Shell` (or the `Composite` to which you can narrow it down) with any search algorithm you want (DFS, BFS, ...) and then compare the `UUID` to the id you are searching for.

```
for(Control control : shell.getChildren())
{
    UUID id = (UUID) control.getData();

    if(id.equals(WHATEVER_HERE))
    {
        System.out.println(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: But is there a way to get all widgets, so I can iterate and find the one I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4):

In your Composite / UI part you set the data with the default SWT Bot Key or with your custom key

```
textOne.setData("org.eclipse.swtbot.widget.key", "textId1");
textTwo.setData("com.sample.my.custom.key", "textCustomId2");
```

In your SWTBot Test you can get the text as follows

```
// using the default SWTBot Key
botTextOne = bot.textWithId("textId1")
```

and

```
//using your custom key
botTextTwo = bot.textWithId("com.sample.my.custom.key", "textCustomId2")
```

References:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWTBot/article.html
- http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/helios/dev-build/apidocs/org/eclipse/swtbot/swt/finder/package-summary.html